# Watch next object in NSEnumerator

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsenumerator

I have a NSEnumerator object with the text lines retrieved from a NSTextView, parsed with:

```
NSEnumerator *myLines = [[allTheText componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] objectEnumerator];
```

I'm processing the lines inside a for cycle like this:

```
for (NSString *current_line in myLines)
{
     //doing something

}
```

This works fine, but now I need to watch the next object while processing the current one. What would be the best way to do this without disrupting the current cycle? If I do something like this (inside the current cycle), it won't work:

```
//inside the previous cycle                    
NSString *next_line;

if (next_line = [myLines nextObject])
{
   //process next line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard for loop:

```
for(uint i = 0; i < [myLines count]; i++) {
    ...
}
```

You'd be able to get previous and next lines be using iteration index:

```
[myLines objectAtIndex:(i-1)]; // previous
[myLines objectAtIndex:(i+1)]; // next
```

Make sure to check for their existence first.

**update**

```
NSArray *lineArray = [allTheText componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Use array above in the for loop.

Comment: But myLines is NSEnumerator (not NSArray) and it won't answer to count or objectAtIndex. I've tried before with [myLines allObjects] but the count always returns 0. Am I missing something?

Comment: how are you receiving the myLines variable?

Comment: It's written in the original post (NSEnumerator *myLines = [[allTheText componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] objectEnumerator];)

Comment: It seems there is not way to "peek ahead" using NSEnumerator. It's nature is just for "walking" the list until it reaches the end. I've implemented a retainer for the last object and process it in the next cycle (with delay). Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm dealing with very large documents, so I believe it's a performance loss to use an array instead of the enumerator. Anyway my question was about the enumerator and with it I don't think there is a way to monitor the object ahead.

Comment: I'd suggest at least trying to use `NSScanner` with 2 lines scanned at one time. I think you'd gain performance boost even more.